# Хороший мануал по Makefiles

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

Столкнулся с тем что для Си по работе нужно писать мейк файлы. Все что я нашел это пару манулов на хабре и мануал по гнумейку, но там нету речи про большие проекты, все большие проекты собираются какими-то тулзами вроде автотулз или смейк. Если ли где-то хорошая сатья по этой тематике. Как собирать большие приложения при помощи Make.

Comment: Вам для чего Makefile? Для gnu make? Или для MS make (nmake)? И да, есть такие "костыли", как qmake, которые из простого и понятного файла делают Makefile для нужной системы сборки.

Comment: Поиск книг и статей это действительно оффтопик. В принципе, я даже и не знаю, как переформулировать вопрос... "как писать большие приложения при помощи make" подпадёт под две другие причины закрытия.

Comment: А мне вопрос нравится :)

Comment: @AK Запрос "синтаксис makefie" выдаёт немало справочной информации. Либо конкретизируем - что из неё непонятно, либо уходим в сторону :)

Comment: мы используем GNU MAKE

Comment: Я бы хотел  гайд лайн как надо писать мейкфайлы, какие есть хинты, упрощения, а не как можно.

Comment: *гайд лайн как надо писать мейкфайлы, какие есть хинты, упрощения* — замените слово «мейкфайлы» на «программы на си», и вы сразу ощутите всю глобальность вашего пожелания. ведь «мейкфайлы» — это не просто «хитрые такие файлики с какими-то прибамбасами», а полноценные программы на декларативном языке, исполняемые интерпретатором *make*.

Comment: поставьте пакет make-doc (в дебиан и производных) и откройте файл file:///usr/share/doc/make-doc/make.html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если отвечать на конкретный вопрос, то рекомендую:

1. "Эффективное использование GNU Make" (C)Владимир Игнатов, 2000
2. "GNU Make. Программа управления компиляцией GNU make" Richard M. Stallman и Roland McGrath, перевод (C)Владимир Игнатов, 2000
3. "Autoconf Создание скриптов для автоматической конфигурации" Декабрь 1998
   David MacKenzie и Ben Elliston (Перевод)
4. "GNU Automake" January 1999 David MacKenzie и Tom Tromey (Перевод)

Но, по своему опыту, рекомендовал бы Вам забыть make как страшный сон и пользоваться cmake. Есть отличная книжка на русском языке:

Дубров, Д. В. "Система построения проектов CMake" : учебник; Южный
федеральный университет. — Ростов-на-Дону : Издательство Южного
федерального университета, 2015. — 419 с.
ISBN 978-5-9275-1852-4

Answer (score 0):

> Столкнулся с тем что для Си по работе нужно писать мейк файлы

Это не так. Понимание как устроены Makefile, и autotools, и cmake, и что такое configure, и много чего ещё - полезно, но не обязательно.

Или "по работе" означает, что от вас этого требует работодатель? Тогда это другой вопрос :)

> Как писать большие приложения при помощи Make.

Никак. Большие, маленькие и средние приложения пишутся головой и руками. А при необходимости любая приличная IDE сгенерирует вам скритпты для автономной сборки, поиска зависимостей, и т.д.

Comment: ответ даже появиться не успел, я только первую фразу успел прочитать -- а уже кто-то минус влепил. кто минусовал -- может пояснить за что ставить минус не глядя?

Comment: @AK, я тоже офигел :) Но уже ничему не удивляюсь :)

Comment: Ну так это ж не очень-то и ответ... Но минус не мой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопрос на грани XY, не? Вроде да, на грани закрытия, но, IMHO, может быть интересным, поэтому так и ответил. Впрочем, решать коллективу :)

Comment: @PinkTux, ну для хорошего ответа его бы всё же стоило дополнить описанием make-файлов и как их готовить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ман по makefile - отдельный вопрос (и нехилый), но меня зацепило "Как писать большие приложения при помощи Make." :-)

Comment: А мне кажется, это как раз этот вопрос и есть)

Comment: Если вы придираетесь  к формулировкам, то да вопрос может не очень сформулирован я ищу адеватный гайдлайн по написанию мейкфайлов

Comment: @SkiF, да какие придирки. Все мы через это проходили когда-то :) Но если вам нужен гайд по мейкфайлам, повторюсь: что не понравилось в запросе "синтаксис makefile" в гугляндексе? Если есть непонятности - давайте разбираться.